# Django Saving and loading messages

Tags: javascript, django, django-models

i am making chat app using django, and i follow the tutorial in youtube and documentation and i follow everything they say, but i still get the error

```
chat/
    __init__.py
    consumers.py
    routing.py
    templates/
    urls.py
    views.py
```

This is my code in **consumers.py**

this is the script in my room.html, i already have script in **ReconnectingWebSocket.js**

```
<script>
    var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};
    var username = {{ username }};

    var chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        var author = message['author'];

        var msgListTag = document.createElement('li');
        var pTag = document.createElement('p');
        pTag.textContent = message.content;

        if (author === username){
            msgListTag.className='sent';
        }
        else{
            msgListTag.className = 'replies';
        }
        msgListTag.appendChild(pTag);
        document.querySelector('#chat-log').appendChild(msgListTag);
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };


    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
        var messageInputDom = document.getElementById('#chat-message-input');
        var message = messageInputDom.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'command': 'new_message',
            'message': message,
            'from': username
        }));
        messageInputDom.value = '';
    };
</script>

    class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
        def fetch_messages(self, data):
            messages = Message.last_10_messages()
            content = {
                'messages': self.messages_to_json(messages)
            }
            self.send_message(content)
        def new_message(self, data):
            author = data['from']
            author_user =User.objects.filter(username=author)[0]
            message = Message.objects.create(
                author=author_user,
                content=data['message']
            )
            content = {
                'command': 'new_message',
                'message': self.messages_to_json(message)
            }
            return  self.send_chat_message(content)

        def messages_to_json(self, messages):
            result = []
            for message in messages:
                result.append(self.message_to_json(message))
            return result
        def message_to_json(self, message):
            return {
                'author':message.author.username,
                'content': message.content,
                'timestamp': str(message.timestamp)
            }
        commands = {
            'fetch_messages': fetch_messages,
            'new_message': new_message
        }
        def connect(self):
            self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
            self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )
            self.accept()

        def disconnect(self, close_code):
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
                self.room_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )
        def receive(self, text_data):
            data = json.loads(text_data)
            self.commands[data['command']](self, data)


        def send_chat_message(self, message):
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
                self.room_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': message
                }
            )

        def send_message(self, message):
            self.send(text_data=json.dump(message))

        def chat_message(self, event):
            message = event['message']
            self.send(text_data=json.dump(message))
```

my views.py

```
 return render(request, 'chat/room.html', {
        'room_name_json': mark_safe(json.dumps(room_name)),
        'username':mark_safe(json.dumps(request.user.username)),
    })
```

my models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author.username

    def last_10_messages(self):
        return Message.objects.order_by('-timestamp').all()[:10]
```

this is the error i get

[image]

i get error from this line

```
def messages_to_json(self, messages):
    result = []
    for message in messages:
        result.append(self.message_to_json(message))
    return result
```

**for message in messages:**

UPDATE when i tried this

```
def messages_to_json(self, messages):
    content = {
        'command': 'new_message',
        'message': self.message_to_json(messages)
    }
```

I get this error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your messages instance is not iterable,so you cannot use it in for loop,it is an instance of your Messages model that inherit from models.Model that is not an iterable,so you can simply use your message_to_json function:

```
 content = {
                'command': 'new_message',
                'message': self.message_to_json(message)
            }
```

Comment: when i tried your answer                                                                                         def messages_to_json(self, messages):
        content = {
            'command': 'new_message',
            'message': self.message_to_json(messages)
        }

Comment: dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp'
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/chat/lobby/ [127.0.0.1:31538]
iget this error

Comment: use json.dumps() instead of json.dump(),can u share your tutorial link?

Comment: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_3.html

Comment: this is the youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrKKRRC518Y